# Does anyone know a good pancreatic-cancer metastasis cell line?

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology, cancer

Researching about pancreatic cancer. We have mostly "main-tumor" cell lines in our lab, and I´m currently looking for cell lines originating from metastases (liver, lung, etc.).
Does anyone know a well-established pancreatic-cancer-metastasis-cell line?

Comment: Did you check [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2860631/) article?

Comment: Thanks, but I already know this one. Good paper nonetheless

Comment: Perhaps you should mention that and explain what different do you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SUIT-2 cell lines are derived from the liver metastases of Pancreatic Ductal Adenocarcinoma. The subline S2-007 is highly metastatic. The other sublines are S2-013, S2-020 and S2-028 which have decreasing metastatic capabilities.

You can probably refer these articles for more info :
1. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/3102439
2. https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10585-017-9840-3